# Im trying to compare two variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, string-comparison

It will have one of the variables defined and the other is defined when you typed if what you typed is the same it has the variable it says correct word and if they are not the same it says an incorrect word. My problem is that always say an incorrect word

```
function wordcompare() {
  var word1 = "word";
  var typed = document.getElementById("word");

  if (typed === word1) {
    alert("Correct word");
  } else {
    alert("Incorrect word");
  }
}
```

Comment: If `word` is an input element you need to get the `value` of that input: `document.getElementById("word").value`. Welcome to SO, Gerard. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you've worked on to solve the problem should include a [mcve], and be included in your question.

Comment: now none of the alerts appear when you click the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I'm assuming you have an input element, and a button, and when you click the button it calls the function to make the comparison.

You need to get the *value* from the input element, otherwise you're just returning the element, and you can't make a comparison with that.

```js
// Cache the elements
const input = document.querySelector('input');
const button = document.querySelector('button');

// When the button is clicked call the function
button.addEventListener('click', wordCompare, false);

function wordCompare() {

  const word1 = 'word';

  // Get the value from the input element and
  // then make the comparison
  if (input.value === word1) {
    console.log('Correct word');
  } else {
    console.log('Incorrect word');
  }
}
```

```html
<input />
<button>Check word</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to compare the input value with the `word`. What you are comaring is string `word` with `HTMLElement` that is returned by `document.getElementById( "word" )`

when you query for any element using `getElementById` It retuns `HTMLElement` that matches the `id` you passed in as `argument`

```js
function wordcompare() {
  var word1 = "word";
  var typed = document.getElementById("word").value;

  if (typed === word1) {
    alert("Correct word");
  } else {
    alert("Incorrect word");
  }
}

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", wordcompare);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="word">
<button> compare </button>
```